# How to create TV guide in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, pagination

I'm creating a TV script which is (very similar to, but not the same as):

http://library.digiguide.tv/lib/programme/True+Blood-663898/Drama/

http://library.digiguide.tv/lib/programmenextshowing/True+Blood-663898
(this shows an optional field of series/episode number, I have a similar one in my database)

http://library.digiguide.tv/lib/programmenextshowing/12578

For me, I'm having to custom-build this, as a CMS isn't useful, but I am considering CodeIgniter since it's got the pagination function.

How would you handle my situation if you were doing it?

Although the above links use ASP.NET, mine is in PHP.

Comment: You're considering using an entire framework because it does... pagination.

Comment: This questions is far too broad.  It's like asking... "I want to duplicate a site kind of like cnn.com in c#.  Can someone tell me how?"  I would handle the situation like yours by learning PHP and studying up on html, css, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If I was asked to do this I would use:

- curl, to get the xml feeds from content providers
- simpleXML, to parse the xml
- a cup of coffee, to stay awake whilst faffing around with the xml formats from different broadcasters
- MYSQL, to store the data for easy retrieval and searching
- cron, to use curl to update the database every hour/day/minute or whatever was needed
- PHP to do easy selects from the database to show the information

The hard part will be parsing the data from the providers, and keeping enough coffee during that part.